# Get 1st Row of a particular event type in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
Row   EventType   CloudId           ts
1     stop        5201156607311872  2018-07-07 12:25:21 UTC  
2     start       5201156607311872  2018-07-07 12:27:39 UTC  
3     start       5201156607311872  2018-07-07 12:28:15 UTC  
4     stop        5738776789778432  2018-07-07 12:28:54 UTC  
5     stop        5201156607311872  2018-07-07 12:30:30 UTC  
6     stop        5738776789778432  2018-07-07 12:37:45 UTC  
7     stop        5738776789778432  2018-07-07 12:40:52 UTC
```

I have a table structure as above. I want to filter only the first event before the `EventType` of the row changes. i.e `row 2` and `row 3` have the same `EventType`, I need to remove `row 3` from the table. `row 4,5,6,7` have the same `EventType`, I want to keep `row 4` and remove `row 5,6,7`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(eventtype) over (order by row) as prev_eventtype
      from t
     ) t
where prev_eventtype is null or prev_eventtype <> eventtype;
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(prev_eventtype) FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(eventtype) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS prev_eventtype
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
)
WHERE prev_eventtype IS NULL OR prev_eventtype <> eventtype
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'stop' EventType, 5201156607311872 CloudId, TIMESTAMP '2018-07-07 12:25:21 UTC' ts UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'start', 5201156607311872, '2018-07-07 12:27:39 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'start', 5201156607311872, '2018-07-07 12:28:15 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'stop', 5738776789778432, '2018-07-07 12:28:54 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'stop', 5201156607311872, '2018-07-07 12:30:30 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'stop', 5738776789778432, '2018-07-07 12:37:45 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'stop', 5738776789778432, '2018-07-07 12:40:52 UTC' 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(prev_eventtype) FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(eventtype) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS prev_eventtype
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
)
WHERE prev_eventtype IS NULL OR prev_eventtype <> eventtype
```

with result :

```
EventType   CloudId             ts   
stop        5201156607311872    2018-07-07 12:25:21 UTC  
start       5201156607311872    2018-07-07 12:27:39 UTC  
stop        5738776789778432    2018-07-07 12:28:54 UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
Row,
EventType,
CloudId,
ts
from 
(
select
Row,
EventType,
CloudId,
ts,
row_number() over (partition by EventType order by CloudId,Row) as rnk
from table_name
)evnt where rnk=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT` statement to just hide the unwanted rows :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.row = (select min(t1.row) from table t1 where t1.EventType = t.EventType);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. May I know the equivalent of the row operator in BigQuery. The query throws an error:  ` Name row not found inside t at [3:9]`